# Why does my send button keep overlapping my edit text?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have a scrollview with a relative layout inside of it. When I have the relative layout height set to match_parent it does this to the graphical layout and I do not know why it's doing this.          ---PICTURE BELOW---

[image: Button Over Lapping Edit Text Box]

Here is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >      

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First and Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPhone"      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Phone #"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter E-mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Additional Information"
        android:lines="5"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Contact Form"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

I have also tried to set the scroll view width and height to fill_parent and it still does the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the correct positioning of Button

Add  `android:layout_below="@+id/etAdd"` to your button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etAdd"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Send" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it still isn't working. I'm confused hahah

Comment: Never mind. I digress. I missed the layout part of it. Thank you kind stranger

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yourEdt"
        android:text="Send" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it still isn't working.

Comment: you mentioned your button height as 125dp and it must align your bottom based on 125dp so it overlap in edittext

Comment: Thank you. It was just missing the layout part of android:below. So it works when you type android:layout_below.

Comment: Is there any default size that I could use to avoid that error?

Comment: you can use wrap_content to your text heght if you used then it will wrap the height based on your text :)